# How does height: 100% work on relative divs?

Tags: css, height, css-position

How is it so that height: 100% actually works on the .rel div?
I know for sure that relative divs never taken percentage heights in account in the past...

```css
.box{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.rel{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

a{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
}

b{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="rel">
    <a> aa  </a>
    <b> bb </b>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Always worked fine. Even works in IE6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative divs can use percentage heights if their parents (`box`, in this case) are also given a height. Since you've given `box` a height of 200px, giving `rel` a percentage height actually means something. If its parent does not have a height defined, `rel`'s height will be meaningless since its parent has no height. If you remove `box`'s height, changing `rel`'s height will do nothing, as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/sxv9jLdz/